# Can according to quantum mechanics, an electron be in the middle of a nucleus of an atom when observed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

you know how because of superpositions and wave functions and probability amplitudes, you can never know the position of an electron? It only takes one spot when we observe it which could be anywhere in the universe due to quantum tunneling ....So, despite its super extremely small chance, could an electron be measured in the middle of the nucleus of an atom, when observed?...or could it be at the edge of the universe when you (or some alien) observe it?

Answer (score 1):

Atomic s-electrons have a finite probability density at the nucleus. In the case of an unpaired s-electron and a nucleus with spin this gives rise to the Fermi contact hyperfine interaction. [21 cm radio astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line) is based on the [Fermi contact interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_contact_interaction) in atomic hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes!

My simple - not mathematical - reasoning for it is the [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture), which is a type of radioactive decay, in which a electrically neutral atom absorbs an inner atomic electron, usually from the K or L electron shells. Knowing that most nuclear decays are explained by the quantum tunneling phenomena, I think it is fair to assume that the electron capture decay is an analogous effect.